# Dynamic Angular localization with django?

Tags: angularjs, django, localization

I have a Angular/Django app and I'm looking at options for localization.

Right now I am loading the django jsi18n script to get the javascript_catalog, and reloading the page whenever the language changes to get the new javascript_catalog for that language.

However I would like to have the language change happen dynamically, but would still like to use the djangojs.po/djangojs.mo file. What are the best practices for this?

I could try to dynamically load the javascript_catalog from django whenever the language changes, but it seems difficult to dynamically load javascript libraries with Angular.

I could also write something  to just load all of the javascript language catalogs on page load, which might be the best option.  Is anything like this already available through Django?

I can't find much on this subject and am wondering how other people have approached this.

Ideally I would also like to use this with Angular-translate.

Comment: I've researched this  more and I've realized that all I need to do is to use something like grunt_po2json_angular_translate to transform the .po files into .json.  I can then do an asynchronous load of the json files through angular-translate.  I don't need to involve Django at all.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved easily this way:
define id for each label and set class='multilang'
define texts, e.g.

```
var a = {}
a['l1'] = {en:'One', de:'Eins', es: 'Un'}
a['l2'] = {en:'Two', de:'Zwei', es: 'Dos'}
```

define function, which finds all elements by class 'multilang' and changes the texts based on ids
call the function when you want to change the language

Btw. you can load the language data asynchronously e.g. using d3.csv or d3.json.

Answer (score 0):

What I am actually trying to do with the Django part is to load the translations from the djangojs.mo file.  I'd like to be able to use .po and gettext.

I'll edit my question to make this clearer.